# Create an Eclipse plugin with customizable key bindings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried to create an Eclipse plugin with commands with customizable key bindings.
I tried with this plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            description="Do something"
            id="com.myplugin.myCommand"
            name="My command">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="com.myplugin.myCommand"
            contextId="org.python.pydev.ui.editor.scope"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="Ctrl+Return">
      </key>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

The default binding <kbd>Ctrl+Return</kbd> works perfectly, but it does not appear in the preferences. What is missing to make it appear in the preferences, so that the user can customize the key binding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try Adding `categoryId` to your command definition.

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <category
        id="com.myplugin.myCategory"
        name="My Category" 
        description="My Category">
  </category>
  <command
        description="Do something"
        id="com.myplugin.myCommand"
        categoryId="com.myplugin.myCategory"
        name="My command">
  </command>
```